# Select all but on element in JOIN MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the code here to join two tables. However I don't want to get the password element from the Accounts database. How could I do this?

```
"SELECT f.*, a.* 
   FROM Following as f 
   JOIN Accounts as a on f.followingUserID = a.id 
  WHERE `followingUserID` = '$acID'
```

Comment: list the fields you do want to select then.

Comment: select all the fields you DO want by name

Answer (score 1):

There is no SQL convention for "all columns EXCEPT FOR ..." -- it's either all, or you define the list by hand:

```
SELECT f.*, 
       a.col1, a.col2,
       a.`col name using spaces not good`
  FROM FOLLOWING as f 
  JOIN ACCOUNTS as a on f.followingUserID = a.id 
 WHERE f.followingUserID = '$acID'
```

Comment: what if there is a space in the column name?

Comment: not good general practice, but if you must you can just quote it

Comment: @RhumSHISH: As Dagon says, not a good practice -- use backticks for such cases (as well as if naming columns using reserved keywords). See the update.

Comment: for 'Email Address', I put `a.Email Address` and I get the error: Unknown column 'a.Email Address' in 'field list'

Comment: for 'Email Address', I put a.Email Address and I get the error: Unknown column 'a.Email Address' in 'field list'

Comment: @RhumSHISH: Yes, which is why the answer was updated to say "use backticks" and provided an example.

Answer (score 0):

Name the columns instead of retrieving them all.

Instead of a.*, :

a.ColumnName1, a.ColumnName2, etc....

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to select a password element you will need to change the `a.*` to select each column individually i.e.

```
SELECT f.*, a.account_id, a.name 
FROM following as f 
JOIN accounts as a on f.followingUserId = a.id 
WHERE followingUserID = '$acID'
```